# Scope of variable on Java thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Consider this snippet.

```
private String global_s;

public void onClick(View v) {
global_s = "String";

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        final Bitmap bitmap = loadImageFromNetwork("http://example.com/image.png");     
        ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        final String local_s = global_s;
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
        tv.setText(local_s);
        });
    }
  }).start();
}
```

Will bitmap reference still alive (not collected by Garbage Collector) after the Thread ended ? since it's assigned on mImageView.

Also, how about local_s ? Will it reference be replaced with global_s reference ?

Comment: Scope is a compile time concept that defines the use of names in a program. Reachability is a run time concept that describes what objects are retrievable through program execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `bitmap` and `local_s` are local variables and therefore disposed as soon as `run()` ends (think milliseconds). However the Bitmap and the String objects will likely be stored as instance fields in the ImageView and TextView objects, sharing their lifespans (think seconds).

About the link between `local_s` and `global_s`: `local_s` captures the value of `global_s` at the time of assignment but is almost useless since it's then immediately passed to `.setText()` - note that Java is always pass by value, so another copy is immediately made and handed to `.setText()` that likely stores it in an instance field that is read at painting time to render the text.

Answer (score 1):

The GC will not destroy objects which are still reachable; i.e., so long as they have a reference, they will not be collected. If you have 5 minutes, skim this [article](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works.html), which provides an excellent, readable description of how Java garbage collections works.

Anyway, `local_s` just references the same object that `global_s` references. The `local_s` reference variable be destroyed as the thread's call stack is destroyed, but `global_s` still owns a handle to its `String` object on the heap. And since `mImageView` exists outside of the thread, its referenced objects will also not be collected once your local thread exists.

Comment: So that means bitmap reference not collected by GC after the Thread ended ?

Comment: The _reference variables_ are destroyed. The _objects they reference_  are not, so long as something else references to them. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12429953/2356554) for a great explanation.

Comment: Sure -- check the SO answer in the comment I just edited -- it's pictures help :)

Comment: Call stacks don't return from threads.  That makes no sense.  Are you trying to say that the JVM may re-use the memory that was occupied by the call stack after the thread has been destroyed?